# "Better keep" vs "Better to keep."

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

Which one is correct (when it comes  at the beginning of the sentence)?

I searched on [this](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=%22better%20keep%22%20%2Fr%3As&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=) website, and I found both instances:

> **Better keep** a close eye on it to make sure it doesn't take over.
>
> **Better to keep** your mouth shut and be thought a fool, than to speak and prove it.

Which version is correct? Or maybe both are correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Better keep a close eye on that.

better keep is a *shortened form* of: **had better**, the modal.

[You had] better keep a close on on that.

2. Better to [do whatever] than to do [whatever else].

better to is a *shortened form* of: **It is better to [do this (rather) than that]**.

Comment: What a superb answer.